# Codility Counting Lesson

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, swap

I'm studying Codility Counting Lesson (https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf) and I need help to understand the fastest solution.

I am wondering why the difference is divided by 2 in line 8 `d //= 2`? Shouldn't the difference be sufficient to find the elements that we can swap between the arrays?

The Problem:

> You are given an integer `m` (`1 < m < 1000000`) and two non-empty,
>   zero-indexed arrays `A` and `B` of `n` integers, `a0`, `a1`, ... ,
>   `an−1` and `b0`, `b1`, ... , `bn−1` respectively (`0 < ai`, `bi < m`).
>   The goal is to check whether there is a swap operation which can be
>   performed on these arrays in such a way that the sum of elements in
>   array `A` equals the sum of elements in array `B` after the swap. By
>   swap operation we mean picking one element from array `A` and one
>   element from array `B` and exchanging them.

The solution:

```
 def fast_solution(A, B, m):
   n = len(A)
   sum_a = sum(A)
   sum_b = sum(B)
   d = sum_b - sum_a
   if d % 2 == 1:
       return False
   d //= 2
   count = counting(A, m)
   for i in xrange(n):
       if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
           return True
   return False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A swap between `A[i`] and `B[j]` adds `B[j]-A[i]` to `sum(A)` and **subtracts** the same value from `sum(B)`; therefore it affects the difference of the sums by **twice** `B[j]-A[i]`.

As a consequence, it's correct to halve the original difference (after checking it's even -- if it's odd no swap will work!-) to form the target for a possible swap.

Note also that the `counting` function they provide is not optimal modern Python -- to avoid reinventing the specific wheel of "counting items", see https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter for Python 2, or https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter for Python 3.

Comment: `As a consequence, it's correct to halve the original difference (after checking it's even -- if it's odd no swap will work!-)` why exactly swap won't work if the difference is odd?

Comment: @dhblah, if the difference between the sums of the two arrays of integer is odd, there is clearly **no** way to equalize the sums by swapping -- easy to prove that if the diff between the sums is odd so is the sum of the sums, so what would you "equalize" each sum to?  A fraction?  Can't be done, obviously!-)

Comment: `easy to prove that if the diff between the sums is odd so is the sum of the sums` - yes I can prove that. But still how does it make it impossible?

Comment: @dhblah, if `sum(A)+sum(B)` is odd, given that a swap can't change that sum of sums, to what value would you want to equalize the sums?  It would have to be an odd number divided by 2, e.g a non-integer fraction, but that can't happen since all items of A and B are integers.  Not a programming problem, just one of simple logic and arithmetic, so take it e.g to math.stackexchange.com if you still can't see it.

Answer (score 4):

Let `Ea = a0 + a1 + .. + a(n-1)`. Let `Eb = b0 + b1 + .. + b(n-1)`. Then swapping element `ai` and `bj` would cause the following effects on those sums: `Ea - ai + bj`, `Eb + ai - bj`. According to the Problem description, then those sums should be equal, so `Ea - ai + bj = Eb + ai - bj` Let's designate  `d = bj - ai`. Then we have the following equality: `Ea + d = Eb - d` which gives us `2d = Eb - Ea` or `d = (Eb - Ea)/2`. For the case when (Eb - Ea) is odd please see the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581933/codility-counting-lesson/27581991?noredirect=1#comment44178834_27581991) from Alex Martelli

The only thing left is to find such `bj` and `ai` so that `bj - ai = d`.

Comment: What is the purpose of m?